# Permanent timer on Python

Tags: python-2.7

I have been recently working with Python, and I wish to make a program that tells me how long was the last time I inputted something without it closing (e.g. The first thing I input is the word "foo". After 15 minutes, I input foo again, so the program prints that I last inputted the word foo 15 minutes ago).

Any ideas on how to make such a script? (Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

Record the time using [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) and every `input()` in a dictionary. Then record the time again the second time it is entered and take the difference in time. The difference is in seconds, so [`divmod()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) it by 60 to get the minutes and seconds.

```
import time
inputs = {}
while True:
    i = input("Type something. ")
    t = time.time()
    if i in inputs: #The input was inputted previously
        time_diff = t-input[i]
        minutes, seconds = divmod(time_diff, 60)
        print("You typed that", minutes, "minutes and", seconds, "ago")
    inputs[i] = t
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to tell you the last time you entered anything or a specific word?

If it's a specific one, make a dictionary where you use words as keys, and then store the time there.